# Reading an excel file, extracting each cell value as a str and doing some action on each cell value, Python

Tags: python, django

I have uploaded an excel file, what I need to do is extract each cell value as str object from the uploaded file and run a query on the cell value.

Unfortunately, nothing is working.

```
def read_agent_list(request):
    request.session.clear_expired()
    
    if request.is_ajax():
        if request.method == "POST":
            userfile = request.FILES['userfile'].read()  
            df = pd.read_excel(userfile,header=0)
            df=df.fillna('')
            df=df.astype(str)
            

            for index, row in df.iterrows():
                agentcode=tuple(list(df['Agentcode']) )
                agentlist=df.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip())
                qry=getData("""
                SELECT U.USER_ID AS AGENTCODE""".format()

                dff=getViaData(qry)
```

Answer (score 1):

To access each cell of excel you can use the following approach:

```
for col in df.columns:
    for row in range(df[df.columns[0]].count()):
        cell = df[col][row]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but my concern here is to work on value I extracted on the cell and run a select query on that value. Is that possible?